# location of Ionic config.json file in windows

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

where is the location of ionic/config.json in windows 10, I tried to search inside C:/ Drive & also inside node directory. but I not see any folder like ionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ionic global config file will be in your user folder `C:\Users\username\.ionic`

The project configuration file will be in your project's root directory as `ionic.config.json`